# CJK package and \figurename

Tags: floats, cjk, naming, japanese

I'm using the [`cjk`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cjk) package to typeset a Japanese document, but somehow can't change the `\figurename` into CJK. I tried in the preamble,

```
\renewcommand{\figurename}{図}
```

but it only give me an empty string before the figure number in the figure captions. Could anybody tell me the way out?  I'm using `\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min} ... \end{CJK}` in the main part.

(I need to use CJK instead of XeLaTeX, because I need to post the document to a preprint server which doesn't have Unicode-enabled TeX system.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You should put the redifinition in a `CJK` environment.
2. Make it global.

Because of 1, you cannot directly use

```
\renewcommand{\figurename}{図}
```

in the preamble.

Because of 2, you cannot use

```
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{図}
\end{CJK}
```

in the preamble either.

---

Solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJK}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{図}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\caption{test}
\end{figure}
\clearpage\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

Better solution:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} % \partformat in ja.cpx is defined
\usepackage{CJK}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}
\CJKcaption{ja} % Input ja.cpx for Japanese, UTF8 encoding
\begin{figure}[ht]
\caption{test}
\end{figure}
\clearpage\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```