# question regarding CJK, mbox, and newcommand

Tags: math-mode, macros, cjk, japanese

I am having quite a difficult time understanding the following behavior. I am trying to use a Japanese character in math mode. Within a certain latex document using CJK, the following code renders correctly:

```
We have $x = \mbox{山}$
```

That is, I am able to place kanji within \mboxes within equations, and everything works fine. However, if I try instead:

```
\newcommand{\san}{\mbox{山}}
...
\begin{document}
We have $x = \san$
```

the resulting output reads as "x = (blank space)" Here is a working/non-working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{CJK}
\newcommand{\san}{\mbox{山}}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}
The equations $x = \san$ and $x = \mbox{山}$ should look the same.
\end{CJK}

\end{document}
```

When I compile the above example with pdflatex, I get: "The equations x = and x = 山 should look the same." My question is: Is there a way to define the macro \san to generate the correct behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must define the command in a CJK environment. Then you must make the definition global.

```
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{}
\gdef\foo{山}
\end{CJK}
```

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24878/cjk-package-and-figurename/24883#24883

Answer (score 4):

Since you seem to be using mainly UTF8 encoding, loading the `CJKutf8` package worked for me.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\newcommand{\san}{\mbox{山}}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}
The equations $x = \san$ and $x = \mbox{山}$ should look the same.
\end{CJK}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `CJK` environment is responsible to assign a meaning to the byte clusters that form the CJK characters (TeXnically, it activates those characters). When you give the definition of `\san`, the three bytes forming 山 are not active and they remain such when `\san` is expanded.

Solution. Perform the definition when the character are interpreted correctly:

```
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}
\gdef\san{\mbox{山}}
\end{CJK}
```

You can't use `\newcommand`, because it doesn't perform global definitions, unless you say

```
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}
\globaldefs=1
\newcommand{\san}{\mbox{山}}
\end{CJK}
```

but I would not use this, as it appears that `\end{CJK}` may perform assignments which would be global as well (and might not be intended to be).